# In the "A Wizard in Rhyme" series how do wizards normally learn magic?

Tags: magic, wizards, a-wizard-in-rhyme

How do wizards normally learn their spells/rhymes in the "[A Wizard in Rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wizard_in_Rhyme)" series? It’s not very clear to me how they go around doing it.